# react-native run-ios child_process.js:506 throw err

Tags: react-native

I am import a new React-Native project. But I can't solve this problem as shown below. Can anyone help me?[image]
Versions  react-native:0.17;
          node:6.4.0;

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to upgrade to newer RN version. The newest one is 0.31. Run `react-native upgrade` after that.

Comment: Other colleagues can run this project and the version is 0.17.So i think I must make some mistakes but i can not figure out...